# Difference between while loop and for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to Java.

If you want to know what I'm trying to solve, check this: http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/200/B

The two versions of the code, solve the same problem:

1-(for loop) version

```
public static void method() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += (sc.nextInt() / 100.0);

    System.out.println(sum * 100.0 / n);
}
```

2-(while loop) version

```
    public static void method() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    double sum = 0;

    while (n-- > 0) {
        sum += (sc.nextInt() / 100.0);
    }
    System.out.println((sum * 100.0) / n);
}
```

===================================================

Here is the input for each of them:

3

50 50 100

Here is the output of each of them:

1-(for loop):    66.66666666666667

2-(while loop):    -200.0

===================================================

Why the output differs?

Comment: For me, the while approach returned -150.0, not -200.0. Anyways: In the while approach you modified `n` and used it after modification in `... / n`.

Comment: Did you try stepping through this with a debugger?

Comment: BTW: In the case above, there is no difference between the for- and the while-loop!

Answer (score 1):

`n--` this will change the value of `n` and it will make it `-1` at end.
so your sum will devide by `-1`  and you get `-200` but in first solution `n` does not change and at end `200/3 = 66.6`

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are decrementing n and then evaluating which will allow n to become negative

```
-- X = decrement X then evaluate 


X -- = evaluate X then decrement X
```